# iOS Mail.app line-break in text body

Tags: ios, html-email, line-breaks, mailto

I have a simple `div` with `onclick` attribute. The attribute contains a `mailto` achor tag so if the visitor click on the div his/her mail client pops up with a new mail window.

My problem is that I have a sample tag in the mail body with line breaks. In OS X Mail.app, Windows' Outlook, Gmail and even in my Windows Phone 7.5 default mail client it works perfectly but on my iPhone or iPad there are no line-breaks.

For line-breaks I use the following code: `\u2029`.

I copy the whole code so you can understand my problem:

```
<?php
    $linebreak = '\u2029';
    $signup_email = 'hello@company.com';
    $signup_subject = 'Signup';
    $signup_body = 'Dear Company,'. $linebreak . $linebreak .'I would like to signup as the following'. $linebreak .'My name: '. $linebreak .'My e-mail: '. $linebreak . $linebreak . $linebreak .'Best regards, '. $linebreak;
?>
<div id="signup" class="left" onclick="location.href='mailto:<?=$signup_email;?>?subject=<?=$signup_subject;?>&body=<?=$signup_body;?>';">Signup</div>
```

The sample text is just a sample text, I don't want to make a signup form like this (it would be so lame (: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just figured it out.

[In this post](http://www.cubetoon.com/2008/how-to-enter-line-break-into-mailto-body-command/) the author says you should use %0D%0A squence to break lines. And it works! I tried in Gmail, OS X default Mail.app, MS Outlook and Thunderbird on Windows XP/7, Windows Phone 7.5, iOS 5.1 and iOS 4.2.1.